# Is there some hint to find a optimizing function?

Tags: analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

How to find a function $y:[0,1] \rightarrow [0, +\infty), y=y(x), x \in [0, 1]$ to make $\int_0^1y(x)dx$ minimum with the following restrictions:

$\begin{array}{cc} y(0) &=& 0, \\
\int_0^1y(t)r(1-t)dt &=& C
\end{array}$

where $C>0$ is a constant, and $r(x)$ is a known rational function, $r(x) = \frac{ax + b}{x + b}$, where $0<a<1$ and $b>1$ have been known.

I think the problem may be applied with some method from the calculus of variations. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This constant $C$ depends on $a$, $b$?

Comment: you say $(ax+b)/(x+b)$. Are you sure it is not $(ax+b)/(x+c)$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I sure.

Comment: Your second condition can be put into the form $(y * r)(1)=C$ i.e., value at $x=1$ of the convolution of "causal" functions $y$ and $r$ ; are you familiar with these concepts ? Besides, I am not sure it is beneficial for the problem, although my experience is that recognizing this sort of forms may be of interest... Another remark: as $r(x)=1+(a-1)x/(x+b)$, it looks important to know if $a$ is $>1$ or $<1$ (and whether $b>0$ or not).

Comment: @JeanMarie I know it's a convolution. $0<a<1, b>1$.

Answer (score 1):

I presume here (as there is some lack of precision in the question) that $r(1-t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, that
$M=\max\{r(1-t): 0\leq t\leq 1\}$ is positive and  also that
 $C$ is positive.

When $y\geq 0$ the inequality:

$$ C=\int_0^1 y(t)r(1-t)\; dt \leq M \int_0^1 y(t)\; dt $$
shows that $I=\int_0^1 y(t)\; dt \geq C/M$. Let the max of $r$ be attained at $t_0$. Then for $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ so that $r(1-t)\geq M-\epsilon$ for $t\in J=[t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta]\cap [0,1]$. If $y$ has support in $J$ then we also have the lower bound:
 $$ C=\int_0^1 y(t)r(1-t)\; dt\geq (M-\epsilon) \int_0^1 y(t)\; dt $$
So $I\geq C/(M-\epsilon)$. The infimum value is thus $C/M$ but it need not be attained unless there is some interval on which $r$ attains its maximum.
The upshot is that we concentrate the 'mass' of $y$ around the point $t_0$ so as to satisfy the constraint in the most economical way (smallest integral of $y$).

If $C$ is negative then $r$ has to negative for some values (or else the constraint can not be satisfied). Letting $m<0$ be the minimum of $r$, the inf of $\int_0^1 y\;dt$ is then $(-C)/(-m)>0$ (seen as above by concentrating the mass of $y$ near the minimum of $r$).

Comment: @Rugh Thanks. I've updated $y(x)$'s definition in my question: $y(x) \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$.